# Algorithm to determine which lists satisfy requirement

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations

I got stuck coming up with an algorithm and I don't know what to do now.

I need to get from `a` to `d` but only by scrolling through these lists:

```
[e, d]
[a, b, c]
[d, a]
[a, b]
[a, e, b]
```

This is of course a simple example and the solution is:

```
[a → d]         // 3rd line
[a → e → d]     // 5th line + 1st line
[a → b → e → d] // 2nd + 5th + 1st line
```

But I have to solve it in *Python*.
I came up with two ways to solve this, the first was using for-loops, but the loops started repeating and got very time consuming, so I went with idea number 2.
I was thinking of creating a list of all possible variants that start with `a` and end with `d`. And then check if this is possible in our specified lists.

```py
from itertools import permutations
 
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

x = 'a'
y = 'd'

for i in range(1, len(lst)):
    perm = permutations(lst, i+1)

    for j in list(perm):
        if (j[0] == x) and (j[-1] == y):
            print(j)
```

But then somehow I got stuck and I don't know what to do now. Could someone please give me a hint? Or am I going about this all wrong?

### edit:

I'm trying to find all the paths and print them.

Comment: Can't you just check the first and last members of each permutation?

Comment: why don't you create an adjacency list and traverse the graph to find your solution? Is there any requirements on the path (like does need to be the shortest). If not you could do either of bfs or dfs. What do you need to show as the result at the end? The path that lead to the target?

Comment: Do you want all the permutations for `a` and `d`?

Comment: I don't understand how your example works.  If you can get from `a` to `d` using the third list what's the second line have to do with anything?  Or is the goal to find all possible paths?  (but then why would a->b->e->d not be one?)

Comment: It sounds like you're given a list of lists, where each list represents an undirected edge between every consecutive pair of nodes. From here, your task is to display all (unique?) paths from some source node to a destination node. If this is the case, I'd start by building the graph (adjacency list/matrix) based on the input list of edges, then performing a depth first search from the source to the destination (while keeping track of the current path during the search). We'd display the path only if the destination is reached.

Comment: Please write a more descriptive title, maybe something like "How do I find the paths that lead from the start to the end?" but more precise if possible. For tips, see [ask].

Comment: If you are trying to list all possible paths, what is the expected behaviour for cycles? e.g. using your example, `[a → b → e → a → d]` using lines 2, 5, 5, 3, or similarly, `[a → b → e → a → b → e → d]` or `[a → b → e → a → b → e → a → b → e → d]`, etc.

Comment: @Oli Ideally no cycles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a graph problem where the lists are undirected edges between the nodes. For example:

```
[a, b, c]
```

means that there are undirected edges from `a` to `b` and `c`, from `b` to `a` and `c`, and from `c` to `a` and `b`. Of course, `a` -- `b`, also means `b` -- `a`. I have repeated the edges above only for clarity.

So, what you want to do is to create an adjacency list that represents all of these edges and apply backtracking since you want all the possible paths from source to target.

Here is some code that shows you the idea:

```
adj_list = collections.defaultdict(set)
for row in rows:
  for i, el in enumerate(row):
    for j in range(i+1, len(row):
        adj_list[el].add(row[j])
        adj_list[row[j]].add(el)

def backtrack(node, adj_list, seen, partial_res, res):
  if node == target:
    res.append(partial_res[:])
  
  for neighbor in adj_list[node]:
    if neighbor in seen: continue
    seen.add(neighbor)
    partial_res.append(neighbor)
    backtrack(neighbor, adj_list, seen, partial_res, res)
    partial_res.pop()
    seen.remove(neighbor)

res = []
backtrack(start, adj_list, set(), [], res)
print(res)
```

I haven't run this. But the code should give an idea of how backtracking works. It's a dfs where you check each possible path and keep track of the edges that you traveled. If it leads to destination, you save a copy of it in your final results.

Please note that this algorithm only visit each node once in each path.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found the `networkx` library that can do exactly what I wanted using the `list(nx.all_simple_paths(G, x, y))` command.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you for sharing. I didn't know about `networkx`.